# Sharepoint Excel files Capacity Planning

Tags: 2013, document-library, excel, excel-services, capacity-planning

I have requirement to upload 30K records every year in document library and further attach workflow and do some stuff based on business criteria.

I need to plan for capacity in SharePoint, so I need to know how many Excel sheets can I store in SharePoint 2013? Also I want to know the best practices to store Excel documents in SharePoint.

Every year if I have 30K files, after 5 years I will have 150000 records in my document library. Will I have a performance hit anytime? If yes, how do ensure I plan it in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper [boundary](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary) for documents is 30 million documents in a library. If you are anticipating this type of growth, you will need to leverage column indexes and ensure you are using filtered views. If you try to render a view that will return more than 5,000 items, you'll throw errors. So don't give out an unfiltered All Documents view.

Carefully plan how people will consume the data and create views as such to ensure you are not returning more than 5,000 items.